# I want to get paginated products depending upon if a user has permissions for that product

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, join, nosql

I want to get paginated products depending upon if a user has permissions for that product.

As you can see below I've queried on the `PersonaEntityPermissionMapModel` model to get all products/productGroups that user has permissions -

```js
PersonaEntityPermissionMapModel.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          $or: [
            {
              personaType: 'User',
              persona: user._id,
              entityType: {
                $in: ['MasterProduct', 'MasterProductGroup'],
              },
            },
            {
              personaType: 'UserGroup',
              persona: { $in: userGroupIds },
              entityType: {
                $in: ['MasterProduct', 'MasterProductGroup'],
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 0,
          entityType: 1,
          entity: 1,
          action: 1,
          actionType: 1,
        },
      },
    ])
```

I've arrived at following data structure -

```js
mappings [
  {
    entity: new ObjectId("63c5571347e5088b199f66b8"),
    entityType: 'MasterProduct',
    action: new ObjectId("63c5571347e5088b199f66ca"),
    actionType: 'Permission'
  },
  {
    entity: new ObjectId("63c5571347e5088b199f66c5"),
    entityType: 'MasterProduct',
    action: new ObjectId("63c5571347e5088b199f66ca"),
    actionType: 'PermissionGroup'
  },
  {
    entity: new ObjectId("63c5571347e5088b199f66cb"),
    entityType: 'MasterProductGroup',
    action: new ObjectId("63c5571347e5088b199f66ca"),
    actionType: 'Permission'
  },
  {
    entity: new ObjectId("63c5571347e5088b199f66cc"),
    entityType: 'MasterProductGroup',
    action: new ObjectId("63c539640253848e04ff8d7a"),
    actionType: 'PermissionGroup'
  }

]
```

`entityType` and `actionType` tells us about the collections to look at. For above data values will be masterproducts/masterproductgroups and permissions/permissiongroups respectively.

I have to do following steps:

1. Need to get all masterproducts from the masterproductgroups.
2. Later for each master product from masterproductgroups I need to have separate entry in above data structure which includes it's `action` and `actionType`
3. I need to group master product by it's Id and collect all unique permissions and permissionGroups
4. After grouping I need to add my pagination stage
5. After pagination I need to populate related master product from the master products collection
6. I also need to populate all actions based on actionTypes(permissions/permissionGroups) and merge them

At the end I want to have all direct/indirect products linked to user with respective permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Asking a big question all together like above was really a idea, That said if you have any suggestions to optimize below query comment them below!

I eventually got the result by using the following query.

```js
  const skip = 0, limit = 10;
  const mappings = await PersonaEntityPermissionMapModel.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        $or: [
          {
            personaType: 'User',
            persona: user._id,
            entityType: {
              $in: ['MasterProduct', 'MasterProductGroup'],
            },
          },
          {
            personaType: 'UserGroup',
            persona: { $in: userGroupIds },
            entityType: {
              $in: ['MasterProduct', 'MasterProductGroup'],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        entity: 1,
        entityType: 1,
        action: 1,
        actionType: 1,
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'masterproductgroups',
        localField: 'entity',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'masterProductGroup',
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: '$masterProductGroup',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        entity: 1,
        entityType: 1,
        action: 1,
        actionType: 1,
        masterProductIds: '$masterProductGroup.masterProducts',
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: '$masterProductIds',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        entity: {
          $cond: {
            if: { $eq: ['$entityType', 'MasterProduct'] },
            then: '$entity',
            else: '$masterProductIds',
          },
        },
        action: 1,
        actionType: 1,
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$entity',
        permissions: {
          $addToSet: {
            $cond: [{ $eq: ['$actionType', 'Permission'] }, '$action', null],
          },
        },
        permissionGroups: {
          $addToSet: {
            $cond: [
              { $eq: ['$actionType', 'PermissionGroup'] },
              '$action',
              null,
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $skip: skip,
    },
    {
      $limit: limit,
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        entity: '$_id',
        permissions: 1,
        permissionGroups: 1,
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'masterproducts',
        localField: 'entity',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'masterProduct',
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: '$masterProduct',
    },
    {
      $project: {
        masterProduct: 1,
        permissions: 1,
        permissionGroups: 1,
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'permissiongroups',
        localField: 'permissionGroups',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'permissionGroups',
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        'permissionGroups.name': 0,
        'permissionGroups.description': 0,
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 1,
        masterProduct: 1,
        permissions: 1,
        permissionGroups: 1,
        allPermissions: {
          $setUnion: [
            '$permissions',
            {
              $reduce: {
                input: '$permissionGroups',
                initialValue: [],
                in: { $concatArrays: ['$$value', '$$this.permissions'] },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 1,
        masterProduct: 1,
        permissions: 1,
        permissionGroups: 1,
        allPermissions: 1,
        allPermissionsFiltered: {
          $filter: {
            input: '$allPermissions',
            as: 'permissionIdOrNullValue',
            cond: {
              $ne: ['$$permissionIdOrNullValue', null],
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'permissions',
        localField: 'allPermissionsFiltered',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'allPermissionsPopulated',
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        masterProduct: 1,
        permissions: 1,
        permissionGroups: 1,
        allPermissions: 1,
        allPermissionsFiltered: 1,
        'allPermissionsPopulated._id': 1,
        'allPermissionsPopulated.name': 1,
      },
    },
  ]);
``
```